# How often is a linq expression on an IEnumerable<T> evaluated?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm a little unsure of deferred execution in the following scenario. How often is the IEnumerable Linq expression evaluated in the following fragment? Would I be better off assigning it to a local variable *before* the foreach loop?

```
foreach (var x in y.Where(s => s.Length > 0))
{
   // do something
}

// where y is, for example, an IEnumerable<string>
```

Comment: `foreach()` is syntactic sugar, it obtains the enumerator and operates on that. Please try searching before asking a new question.

Comment: Please have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement, in particular which gives the expanded version of `foreach (V v in x) embedded_statement`. Does this help answer your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster Calling `foreach` a synctactic sugar is a little overboard. What it does is quite complex and long... Too much long to call it simply synctactic sugar (but you are technically correct... only with your definition we could cut away 90% of the C# language as synctactic sugar probably)

Comment: Codecaster, those questions weren't suggested as possible duplicates, by the way.